# The meaning of saying "Increase in correlation having a negative impact on ability to generate alpha"

Tags: investing

I asked a friend who works at a hedge fund about what is the biggest threat facing the asset management industry.

He gave me a list of bullet points and one bullet point said

"Increase in correlation having a negative impact on ability to generate alpha"

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like something a hedge fund guy would say.  So just tear apart the sentence.

> Correlation: A connection or pairing of two or more things
>
> Alpha: Industry lingo for returns against an index

He's saying securities are becoming more correlated, meaning more securities are moving in tandem, and that makes it difficult to pick the securities that will move more than the market in general, generating a greater return than the market index.